# returning 2 values from array using recursion c++

Tags: c++, recursion, search

### ***This is the code to find a number in the array and return its index. But what if I have the same 2 numbers and I want to return both their indexs ?***

```
int find_pos (int a[], int index, int n)
{


  if ( a[index] == n) 
  {
    return index;
  }

  else
  {
    return find_pos (a, index + 1, n);
  }
}
int main()

{
  int a[] = {3, 1, 5, 6, 0, 6, 8, 4};

  cout << find_pos (a, 0, 6);

}
```

Comment: You can use reference parameters or a small struct to return multiple results from a function.

Comment: Can you please show me how to use both of them

Comment: Your function as is doesn't even return the correct result when `n` isn't the first element..

Comment: Oh thank you ! i just corrected it

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `vector<int>` to hold the indices of found values. That is, instead of returning when you find a matching value, just save the index into your vector and continue searching. This means that your recursion base case has to change. You'll have to search all the way to the end of the array. Since you're using a C-style array, you'll have to also pass in the length of the array too, so that recursive function calls can know when to stop.